# How to test declarative_authorization with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, declarative-authorization

Is there a way to test the declarative_authorization permissions with respect?

In the documentation it has some instructions to use test unit, but I can't seem to find a way to use rspec.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can test permissions. See [here](http://www.tzi.org/~sbartsch/declarative_authorization/master/) under Authorization::TestHelper -- require the helpers in your spec_helper file, and include Authorization::TestHelper. This pulls in methods that allow you to specify the current user and its privileges in rspec's `before` method.

Another tip: to make it easier to create factory objects, declarative_authorization has a `without_access_control` method that allows you to bypass authorization in your `before` sections.

Answer (score 1):

I've manage to use cucumber to test the roles.

Like this:

```
require 'machinist/active_record'
require 'spec/blueprints.rb'

def user  
  @user ||= User.make
end

Given /^I am an Administrator$/ do
  user
  @user.assignments.delete_all
  @user.roles.delete_all
  @user.assignments << Assignment.create(:user_id => @user.id,
                   :role_id =>  Role.find_by_name("admin").id)
  @user.roles.count.should == 1
  @user.roles << Role.find_by_name("admin")  
  Authorization.current_user = @user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all assertion in rspec, so you can use it or convert it in rpsec style.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get that. Can you be a little more specific?